# how to connect local mongo DB instead of docker from sails JS application

Tags: mongodb, docker, sails-mongo

My sails JS application looking for mongo db(Running on docker) , though local mongo db server is available.
If docker is up with mongo db server then application connecting to docker based mongo-DB

```
{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [192.168.99.100:27017] on first connect' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the container connect to a local mongodb you need to get the ip of your host in linux you can type the following command on the host

```
ifconfig docker0 | awk '/inet / { print $2 }'
```

The result will be an ip that can be used to call it from any container followed by the service port which will be `27017` in your case. and make sure that the mongodb is not listening to `127.0.0.1` only.

Comment: SailJS application running locally mongoDB running on docker, so i have to connect to local mongo DB instead of docker based db

Comment: If you want to connect to mongodb locally then this has nothing to do with docker. Just change the settings in your sails application to listen on 127.0.0.1:27017